# MonacaのBasicプランで利用可能なデータベース

Tags: monaca, database

Basicプランでのデータベースは利用可能でしょうか？

・コレクション管理
・Web SQL Database
・Local Strage
・IndexedDB

などが取り上げられていたのですがCordvaのプラグインが必要なものなのかわからなかったので
質問いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の場合、BasicプランでWebSQLとLocalStrageを利用しています。
プラグインを使用せずに利用できます。

[localStorageを使用して端末にデータを保存する](http://blog.asial.co.jp/939)

[データベースの利用方法](http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/sampleapp/tips/storage/)